# Trying to echo MySQL table names onto HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm writing PHP code that will create a SHOW TABLES SQL query and echo the results onto an HTML page. This is what the PHP looks like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    echo("Database used: ".$db);
    echo("<br><br>");
    echo("<u>Tables in ".$db."</u><br>");

    $tables = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SHOW TABLES;");
    while($row = $tables->fetch_row()) {
        echo($row);
        echo("<br>");
    }
```

There are three tables in the database I'm using. However, rather than echo the names of each of those tables it echos the word Array three times. I need to change it so it echos the names of each table in database $db

Comment: well then, at a wild guess, $row is an array

Comment: ...I can't argue with you there, my question is how do I rewrite this so that it echos the names of my tables instead of Array.

Comment: `print_r($row);` what do you get ?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Members ) 1
Array ( [0] => Prints ) 1
Array ( [0] => Users ) 1  which is closer but I want just the names

Comment: that should tell you all you need to know

Comment: Changed it to print_r($row[0]) but now it prints the table names with a 1 after it...

Answer (score 0):

it should be `echo $row['yourtablenamefromarray'];`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$tables = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SHOW TABLES;");
while($row = $tables->fetch_row()) {
   echo $row[0]."<br />".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. I also changed the code to be object-oriented (not sure if that's the right terminology).

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','yourpass','yourdb');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
$statement = $con->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
$statement->bind_result($table);
$statement->execute();
while ($statement->fetch()){
echo $table . "<br>";
}
```